# A function that polls on intervals and yields infinitely

Tags: python, yield

I want to write a function, let's say `yield_posts` that polls a RESTful API regularly and can be used in `for` loop that runs forever, like this:

```py
for post in yield_posts():
    do_something_with(post)
```

I have the following pseudo-code in mind

```py
def yield_posts():
    while True:
        new_posts = request_new_posts()
        time.sleep(10)
        for post in new_posts:
            if check_in_db(post):
                continue
            yield post
            add_to_db(post)
```

Will this work for its intended purpose, or is there a better method?

Answer (score 2):

What you have in mind will work perfectly. When you call the function, it will loop forever, doing its work and then waiting for a given amount of time (10 seconds here). You may want to look into the `Thread` class, however, if you want to do other things while this function is running, as you won't be able to do anything while the function is on `time.sleep().` Not to mention that the `while` loop will mean that the function never ends.

The [Threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module works exactly as it sounds. It creates various threads for you to utilize one thread doing repetitive work (in your case calling a function repetitively every 10 seconds) while leaving the main thread open for other work.

The way I would add your function as a separate thread would be as follows:

```
from threading import Thread
class Yield_Posts(Thread):
    run():
        while True:
            #do whatever you need to repetitively in here, like
            time.sleep(10)
            #etc.

separateThread = Yield_Posts()
separateThread.start()
#do other things here, the separate thread will be running at the same time.
```

Comment: If this function is meant to be imported, this means that the main thread of `__main__` will be free to do whatever while the imported Yield_Posts would run on its own separate thread, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct The bottom three lines are running in the `__main__` thread. As soon as you call `separateThread.start()`, the program creates a new thread and executes the `run()` function in the new thread, leaving the `__main__` thread free to do other things.